# Extending Object prototype in ES6 module gives Property does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: typescript, prototype

I have two modules - mod1.ts and mod2.ts.

```
//mod1.ts
import {Test} from "./mod2"; //LINE X

interface Object {
    GetFooAsString(): string;
}

Object.prototype.GetFooAsString = function () {
    return this.GetFoo().toString();
}

//mod2.ts
export class Test {

    test(): void {
       console.log("Test");
    } 
}
```

if I comment LINE X at mod1.ts and compile it this way: `tsc --module ES2015 --target ES2015 mod1.ts` then everything is ok. However, if I uncomment LINE X and compile both modules: `tsc --module ES2015 --target ES2015 mod1.ts mod2.ts` I get:

```
mod1.ts:7:18 - error TS2339: Property 'GetFooAsString' does not exist on type 'Object'.

7 Object.prototype.GetFooAsString = function () {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to explain and fix it? I use TypeScript 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface you declare is not in the global scope, it's in the current module. You need to declare it in global:

```
import { Test } from "./mod2"; //LINE X
declare global {
  interface Object {
    GetFooAsString(): string;
  }
}

Object.prototype.GetFooAsString = function () {
  return this.GetFoo().toString();
}
```

The reason this happens is that until you add an import or an export the file is considered a simple script and everything is in the global scope. When you add an import/export it becomes a module and thus everything is in the module scope instead.